# HTML5 vector effects

Tags: html, animation, svg, html5-canvas

I have an idea that I would like your input on how it can be achieved. Essentially, I would like to have a page where page elements would be responsive and animated. Let me give you an example - let's say I point my mouse over a button or an image and it would play an animation like http://hakim.se/experiments/html5/magnetic/02/ around it while mouse is pointing over it, fading away if I point away from it. 
Alternatively, it would be cool to have something like http://hakim.se/experiments/html5/trail/03/ flowing from current mouse position to the element that I would like to draw user's attention to. I have little idea on how this can be implemented, thinking that creating a  overlay and using element's coordinates would be most appropriate but not 100% it can be done this way. Do you have any recommendations or suggestions on best practices, existing libraries / frameworks that may assist me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, in the links that you provide is the code to do it. I would set the canvas as the bottom element in you display, and all the remaining elements on it. By the way, the implementation is in canvas, I don't think that SVG would help you here.

Comment: I was wondering about this as well - which technology to use - and starting to lean towards canvas as animations there are controlled by the script. I want to implement good amount of animations and SVG with its implementation rooted in the XML (or SMIL) looks less appealing.